# in UITableviewcell in Xcode 9.0.1 cell size it not expanding at runtime?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have tried with drag and drop UITableviewcell and change row height from file inspector cannot expanded cell height at runtime.

[image: I have tried with drag and drop UITableviewcell and change row height from file inspector cannot expanded cell height at runtime]

in Xcode 9.0.1 I am facing issue regarding Cell height not increasing at run time.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3+** 
If you want dynamic row height, you can define your constraints (making sure they're unambiguous), set the label's numberOfLines to zero, and then in viewDidLoad, tell it that rows should automatically adjust their height:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = your height here
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```

**OR** Try this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your cells to be self-sizing:

1: Add the following lines to viewDidLoad().  Specify a tableViewRowHieght that you think will be the average height of the cells displayd in your tableView:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
```

2: Makes sure all of the labels in your cell are capable of expanding to as many lines as needed.  This is done by setting Number Of Lines in Attribute Inspector to 0 as I have done for my Title label in the image below:

[image]

3: Finally, you must set constraints for every element in your cell so that the compiler can correctly calculate the size of the cell at runtime. Here I've added two lables contrained the height of the first to the top of the view, and bottom to label 2 below.  Then label 2 must be contrained to the bottom of the view.  As long as your contraints contain no "gaps" between the top of the cell to the bottom, the compiler can calculate the height of the cell:

[image]